# Update php version on mac using CLI

Tags: php, macos

I am finding myself in an awkward situation.I'm using mac and when i run php -v command its return

```
PHP 5.5.30 (cli) (built: Oct 23 2015 17:21:45) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

I want to update php latest version and  i had tried this command.

```
curl -s http: //php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.0
```

After Installation Completes then run this command

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

But still php version is 5.5.30 and the second thing i'm using brew and installed php70 with brew install php70 command after that i checked php version its return 5.5.30.Kindly help me how can i update my php version in mac

Comment: I'm not familiar with the install process your using, but I'd put my focus on */usr/local/*php5*/bin:$PATH* (like **php 5**.5.30). I'd expect that path is wrong and your installer put it elsewhere.

Comment: How can correct the path? Hpierce

Answer (score 0):

```
brewinstall php@7.2
```

then

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export > PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

then restart your terminal session

Answer (score 0):

*try this command instead :*
brew install php@7.2